# johnny-five library is not getting detected by npm

Tags: npm, johnny-five, package-lock.json

I tried installing Johnny-five library as specified in the website. After installation while running the code i am getting error as below, please help.

While installing Johnny-five package I got a message such as package-lock.json need to be committed, is it creating any issues?

```
D:\Js-Arduino>node servo.js
module.js:549
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'johnny-five'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Js-Arduino\servo.js:1:74)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.

Moved nodemodules global path to Env variables and Npm started detecting it